# MySQL - select value or return zero?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

1)
STUDENTS

```
ID,  NAME,   LASTNAME,  CLASS, ...and more columns (not important)...
1,   Peter,  Fish,      4A
2,   Johnny, Rock,      4A
3,   Tony,   Martin,    4B
4,   David,  Blur,      4C    
5,   Joe,    Black,     4B
```

2) 
MATH_CLASS

```
STUDENT_ID,  POINTS    
1,           15
1,           20  
2,           30    
3,           11
3,            5
4,            3
```

Now, with

```
"SELECT ID, NAME, LASTNAME, SUM(POINTS) FROM STUDENTS, MATH_CLASS WHERE ID = STUDENT_ID GROUP BY ID"
```

i can get simple list of students followed by sum of the points they have at MATH_CLASS.

What I need is to get the list that contains even the two students who have no entry in MATH_CLASS (either just id and the name with no information after it or followed by 0).

Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: use a "full outer join" - which is not directly available MySQL, but this post explains a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a LEFT JOIN instead.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, LASTNAME, SUM(COALESCE(POINTS)) 
FROM STUDENTS LEFT JOIN MATH_CLASS ON ID = STUDENT_ID GROUP BY ID
```

Note the use of COALESCE to avoid Null apearing in the resultset.

BTW, I highly recommend that you use lower case table and column names.

Comment: Thanks! ...why would you recommend it? ...any specific reason?

Comment: not just because it's the standard practice but because it makes code very much more readble.

Comment: BTW, Since you are still new here, may i point out that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).